# strings and languages in xcode/iphone

Tags: iphone, string, localization

Hi I have a problem with my strings and I have already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199525/adding-localizable-files-to-project-on-xcode-4) and did what was told there but it doesn't work

So for the xib files I have a diferent version for each language and it works. but I have also a file named Localization.strings which for now only contains one string:

"password" = "passwords are not the same";

Then in my code I try to access the localized string:

```
NSString *tp=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"password", nil)];
```

so tp is supposed to have the string "passwords are not the same" but no it returns "password". I have been wondering if it is the right way to write strings maybe you have to write the value itself on the left side??? Anyway I have two versions spanish and english and in both the same thing happens. I have deleted app from the iphone cleaned, changed language and reinstalled and nothing works.

thanks

Comment: Just to comment on the way the `init` your string. There is no need to create a new string just do: `NSString *tp = NSLocalizedString(@"password", nil);`

Comment: thanks rckoenes that way I will save some resources but it doesn't change anything for my problem

Comment: Assuming you are using Xcode 4 did add any language to the `Localization.strings` file? You can add them vie the bar on the right. Also make sure you check the default language of you app. If there is no `strings` file for that language it will use the key and any translation.

Comment: I have the Localization.strings and also 2 more of them each for english and spanish and I am using xcode 4,2 the latest and the default language of the app is "en" (Localization native development region). When I select the Localization.strings on the right i have in the bar you say Localization and English and Spanish are in the list. I did the same for the xib files and it works fine but not the strings. when I debug the tp is not nil (ooo) but I can't see it's value so I suppose the strings are not found....????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is the naming of your *strings*-file. The default file that `NSLocalizedString()` do it's lookup in is `Localizable.strings`.

So rename `Localization.strings` to `Localizable.string`. You could also use a specific file for your lookup if you want too (if you for example split your localized strings into several *strings*-files). Using:

```
NSString *tp = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"password", @"Localization", nil);
```

Comment: you solved my problem. I sow somewhere you can name your files how you want but they don't say you have to specify in your code you called the diferently.

Comment: Damm I misted that one, well lucky some one saw it.